# PHP: Reading huge amount of excel file causing fatal error

Tags: php, excel

i am facing a problem.

I need to read a .xls file of about 10MB. i write a php code that works fine when i read small .xls file. but when i try to read large file then the browser shows **"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1032 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\student\ExcelRes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 1126"**

Here is my code.

```
<?php 

    ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'ExcelRes/');

    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $inputFileName = 'ru_unit_H_all.xls'; 
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);


    echo $sheetData['20007'][ 'K'];          //row colomn

?>
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, `memory_limit` cannot be overwritten by `ini_set()`.

Comment: memory management come to be a real pain in php when parsing files, if you can, optimize PHPExcel to consume less memory. Try increasing memory_limit up to 256M, if you stil have a memory limit error, then parsing may have gone in an infinite loop or recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve my problem by using example12 code.

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'ExcelRes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = 'ru_unit_H_all.xls'; 

class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    private $_startRow = 0;
    private $_endRow = 0;

    public function setRows($startRow) 
    {
        $this->_startRow    = $startRow; 
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '')
    { 
        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow )) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

$objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

$chunkFilter->setRows(22000); 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K22000')->getValue();

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Error message should be self explaining:

*"Fatal error: **Allowed memory** size of 134217728 bytes **exhausted** (tried to allocate 1032 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\student\ExcelRes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 1126"*

You just simply ran out of memory reserved for execution of one script.

You may increase your [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to solve this issue.

*Note:* using `128MB` isn't enough, because [`134217728B = ~128MB`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=134217728%20bytes%20to%20megabytes) still causes that error. Try using `512MB`.

There's no memory effective implementation of Excel reader/writer for PHP that I know of.

Comment: I have already used ini_set() function. but still causing problem

Comment: @ImdadSarkar so use 5GB or different implementation... No much other options there.

Comment: @Vyktor - COM would be memory efficient, because the Excel workbooks are loaded __outside__ of PHP memory... PHPExcel does have some settings for reducing memory requirements, such as cell caching, or loading only parts of the spreadsheet, or loading only data only without the style information; but is still constrained by PHP memory limits

Comment: I am writing excel files with a template load and getting this error --- "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 704384 bytes) in /home/envdev/public_html/app/application/third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 304 "

Answer (score 0):

The memory available to the script has been exausted.  By default I believe each script has a limit of 8MB of memory allocated to it.  You are attempting to read 10MB file, and as such, there is not enough memory to process the requst and it fails.

You can try increasing the amount of memory available, by using `memory_limit` setting.

This can be done globally for all scripts in the `php.ini` settings file or on a per script basis using

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Where `16M` is 16 Megabytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to possibly increasing memory, you should also be looking at the cell caching options provided by PHPExcel for precisely this purpose, as described in the section of the developer documentation entitled "cell caching" (section 4.2.1)

**EDIT**

And your use of toArray() is going to build the array you're requesting in PHP memory as well, adding extra overhead - consider iterating over the worksheet a row at a time rather than loading it twice into memory (once as a PHPExcel object and once as your array)